# Parse.com - Push Notifications configuration problems in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am trying to setup Parse.com push notifications as per the documentation:

My manifest xml has following related entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hello.world"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
....
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- NOTE THIS NEXT LINE -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.hello.world.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.hello.world.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
....

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />           
                <category android:name="com.hello.world" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

After adding the parse.com push related configurations in manifest as above - The application has stopped working - it simply hangs on startup, i do not see the first screen.

**EDIT 1**

After debugging i found that application hangs here when it tries to make the first call to Parse:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("myclass");
List<ParseObject> myclassresult = query.find();//App Hangs at THIS line
```

Why would this happen only when Parse.com push configurations are added?
This line and App works fine without Parse.com push configs

(Also note that i have not done any specific configuration at Parse.com for the application to enable Push, and i am using the normal Parse.com sdk, not any special sdk for push notifications)

**EDIT 2**

When i look at the relevant Threads (AsyncTask#1) Stack Trace i see the following:

```
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)   
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364) 
  at bolts.Task.waitForCompletion(Task.java:119)    
  at com.parse.Parse.waitForTask(Parse.java:721)    
  at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUser(ParseUser.java:1044)    
  at com.parse.ParseQuery.getUser(ParseQuery.java:298)  
  at com.parse.ParseQuery.findInBackground(ParseQuery.java:892) 
  at com.parse.ParseQuery.find(ParseQuery.java:529) 
  at com.hello.world.MyQueryClass.getDataFromParse(MyQueryClass.java:..)    
  ...
```

Comment: Try debugging. See what you get.

Comment: @Tushar i have added what i found as a result of debugging..pls see EDIT 1 in question... thx

Comment: Make sure that you're following the pattern given [here](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications).  Did you add `<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
           android:value="id:YOUR_SENDER_ID" />;` in the `<application>`? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: @Tushar > No i do not have the meta-data tag you suggest above. It is not mentioned in tutorial either. I just want to receive notification, never send out any. I am following documentation mentioned here: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/existing . Also i have no subscribe code in my app at all - it isn't mentioned in the documentation i refer to...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to uninstall and then install the application again.
Just re-installing on top of existing application was not working - and instead causing the odd behavior!

If anyone knows the reason for this - please post a comment.